# Что за ошибка error C2461: 'next' : constructor syntax missing formal parameters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый вечер.
Разбираюсь с чужим кодом, при компиляции выдает ошибку error C2461: 'next' : constructor syntax missing formal parameters. Вот тут:

```
typedef struct next{
      Qlabel *next;
}next;
```

Что это значит. Гуглить пробовал, не помогло. Так что же это такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку объявляется член класса, имеющий то же имя, что и сам класс, компилятор подумал, что это конструктор. А раз это конструктор, нужен список параметров, хоть пустой.

Код неправильный, непонятно, почему он компилировался раньше.

Comment: А он и не компилировался. Спасибо! Заработало)

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Comment: судя по стилю написания кода, оно компилировалось удачно на чистом си. (если припустить. что Qlabel - это другая структура.). Конструкторов там нет, так что никаких проблем.

Comment: @KoVadim: угу, вы правы: http://ideone.com/WYL5aJ